# Decide the development of the expression $(2x − y + z/4)^9$ = $\sum_{i+j+k=9} C_{i, j, k}x^iy^jz^k$ - Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Decide the development of the expression $(2x − y + z/4)^9$

a) The coefficient $C_{2,3,4}$ before $x^2y^3z^4$

b) The sum of the coefficients

c) The number of coefficients $C_{i,j,k}$

Picture below is what I've done so far, but I'm very unsure. Don't really understand question

[Done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8asBN.jpg)

Picture of question:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qJyt.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What coefficients you want to calculate? My guess is that $C_{i,j,k}$ is the coefficient of $x^iy^jz^k$, but you did not explicitly stated this

Comment: @Andrei , First of all sorry! First time posting here and don't know how to get the math symbols in to the text. But I've uptaded the orginal question with a picture of my work so far.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations instead of using an image.

Comment: @Andrei, A kind soul helped me clean the question up a bit, maybe you can help me get a better understanding of the question? Or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part a you are almost there. You just need to expand that $$\pmatrix{9\\2,3,4}=\frac{9!}{2!3!4!}$$
Part b is fine.

For part c they just ask how many of these coefficients you have. You have a coefficient for $x^9y^0z^0$, one coefficient for $x^8yz^0$, one for $x^8y^0z$, and so on. The value is $$\frac{(9+1)(9+2)}{2}=55$$A nice explanation of how to calculate this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/number-of-terms-in-a-trinomial-expansion).